# Unable to make a ScrollView that contains other layouts and widgets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am simply trying to make a scrollable layout with no luck...
I have no idea why it isn't working, it seems to be exactly as I read online.
The problem here is that the bottom of the included layout is cut of to fit exactly the screen size.
this is my layout xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=""
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="opening game"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/GameTitleET"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/GameTitleET"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="153dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Game's name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/GameContentET"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="מהלך המשחק"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="8"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/DeleteAndMakeYOurOwnButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/DeleteAndMakeYOurOwnButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="Write your own game"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/GameContentET"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/numberPicker2" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/SendToReviewSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="הגש משחק להגשה"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/DeleteAndMakeYOurOwnButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include5"
        layout="@layout/activity_create_post_methods"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/GameContentET" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout></ScrollView>
```

Do you have any suggestion of what should i do? I also plan to add many more layouts to this main layout and I need it to scroll and show everything flawlessly.
Thank you a lot!

Comment: did your try **`android:fillViewport="true"`** in your scrollview

Comment: I tried to do that now, ant it seems that the Constraint layout is the one that cut the content, do you have any idea how to solve it? and thank you!

Comment: i think u don't close the `</ScrollView>` at last

Comment: @NegNeg64 you code is working fine in my device

Comment: the included layout is still cut off, the scrollview works fine though

Comment: Do you guys have any idea what can I do in order to fix that?